# Assigning new variable for each loop in a while loop

Tags: python, variables, loops, while-loop

Im trying to reference a line in which the keyword appears if it appears multiple times i need to be able to reference each line from the while loop. Also i need to bold the key word in the line. Thank you!

```
def main():
    print("The Great Search Engine, by Eric Santos")
    # input from user name of database file
    dname = input("Enter name of database file: ")
    # input from user seach term to look for
    term = input("Enter keyword to search for: ")
    # open html file for writing
    outfile = open("mypage.html", "w")

    # open database file for reading
    infile = open(dname,"r")
    # for each line in the file:
    hits=0
    i = 0
    for line in infile:
        listword = line.split()
        for word in listword:
            if term == word:
                print(word)
                print(line)
                # read in URL line
                url = infile.readline()
                print(url)
                hits=hits+1
                i=i+1

    if hits==1:
        print ("Keyword", term, "found", hits,"times")
        print("<html>", file=outfile)
        print("<head><title>Search Findings</title></head>", file=outfile)
        print("<body>", file=outfile)
        print('<h2><p align=center>Search for "', term, '"</h2>"', file=outfile)
        print("<p align=center>", file=outfile)
        print("<table border>", file=outfile)
        print("<tr><th> Hits <th>URL</tr>", file=outfile)
        print("<html>", file=outfile)
        print("<tr><td>",line,"<td><a href=", url,"> ",url,"</a></tr>", file=outfile)
        print("</table>", file=outfile)
        print("</body>", file=outfile)
        print("</html>", file=outfile)

    if hits ==2:
        print ("Keyword", term, "found", hits,"times")
        print("<html>", file=outfile)
        print("<head><title>Search Findings</title></head>", file=outfile)
        print("<body>", file=outfile)
        print('<h2><p align=center>Search for "', term, '"</h2>"', file=outfile)
        print("<p align=center>", file=outfile)
        print("<table border>", file=outfile)
        print("<tr><th> Hits <th>URL</tr>", file=outfile)
        print("<html>", file=outfile)
        print("<tr><td>search <b>engine</b><td><a href=", url,"> ",url,"</a></tr>", file=outfile)
        print("<tr><td>search <b>engine</b><td><a href=", url,"> ",url,"</a></tr>", file=outfile)
        print("</table>", file=outfile)
        print("</body>", file=outfile)
        print("</html>", file=outfile)

        outfile.close()

    if hits == 0:
        print("Keyword", term,"not found")

        # use find to see if search term is in line
        # if find is successful
            # add one to the hits
            # output the file to the html file
    # if after count still zero
        # show to shell no hits
        # output to html file "no hits"
    # else
        # output to shell how many hits
    infile.close()

main()

# write out the end of html to the html file
# close file
```

Comment: I don't have python 3 handy so I can't run your code, but what is your question?  Is the code running? almost running? producing traceback errors or?

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to reference each line from the while loop... but you don't have a while loop in your program.

Also what's the purpose of your variable `hits` and the variable `i`  (why the *two* variables?)

Answer (score 0):

I've made some edits to your code.  I'm using python 2.6 so I changed input to raw_input and added from **future** import print_function

I then changed to do readlines() to read the complete file into line

I split on " " so that you won't split on each character.

I have no idea what you are thinking here:  url = infile.readline()

Your output indicates you want to print a url but you have a text file for input, and that doesn't add up to a url, so think about what you really want there.

Take a look and perhaps refine your question.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def main():
    print("The Great Search Engine, by Eric Santos")
    # input from user name of database file
    dname = raw_input("Enter name of database file: ")
    # input from user seach term to look for
    term = raw_input("Enter keyword to search for: ")
    # open html file for writing
    outfile = open("mypage.html", "w")

    # open database file for reading
    infile = open(dname,"r")
    # for each line in the file:
    hits=0
    i = 0
    for line in infile.readlines():
    print(line)
    listword = line.split(" ")
    print(listword)
    for word in listword:
        if term == word:
            print(word)
            print(line)
            # read in URL line
            url = infile.readline()
            print(url)
            hits=hits+1
            i=i+1
```